# Unexpected Results in Token Swap Calculations from getTransaction

Tags: web3.js, transactions

I have a piece of typescript code finding out the number of tokens swapped in a transaction. This goes well, but in (estimated) 3% of the cases I get a strange result. In the provided code, I get as a result:

```
movedSol -0.010017014
tokenBalanceBefore 24696796.2733421
tokenBalanceAfter 84.022468663
tokenBalanceChanged -24696712.250873435
```

Where I would expect:

```
movedSol -0.010017014
tokenBalanceBefore 24696796.2733421
tokenBalanceAfter 24696712.250873435
tokenBalanceChanged -84.022468663
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Solscan transaction from the example](https://solscan.io/tx/5Wqke2sa3WRzN7GMpGybs8tCETc3mW3zdai7Qq3zpb8xLSbtKSWzs6qqw4kZKjcBaxN18Pnv1tVB6iDV3ShP1M89)

```
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, GetVersionedTransactionConfig, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from '@solana/web3.js';

main();

async function main() {
  const transactionId = '5Wqke2sa3WRzN7GMpGybs8tCETc3mW3zdai7Qq3zpb8xLSbtKSWzs6qqw4kZKjcBaxN18Pnv1tVB6iDV3ShP1M89';
  const tokenAddress = '3ag1Mj9AKz9FAkCQ6gAEhpLSX8B2pUbPdkb9iBsDLZNB';
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');
  const options: GetVersionedTransactionConfig = {commitment: 'confirmed', maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0};
  const transactionResponse: any = await connection.getTransaction(transactionId, options);

  const preSolBalance = transactionResponse.meta?.preBalances[0] || 0;
  const postSolBalance = transactionResponse.meta?.postBalances[0] || 0;
  const movedSol = (postSolBalance - preSolBalance) / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
  const tokenBalanceBefore = transactionResponse.meta?.preTokenBalances?.find(token => token.mint === tokenAddress)?.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount || 0;
  const tokenBalanceAfter = transactionResponse.meta?.postTokenBalances?.find(token => token.mint === tokenAddress)?.uiTokenAmount.uiAmount || 0;
  const tokenBalanceChanged =  tokenBalanceAfter - tokenBalanceBefore;
  console.log('movedSol', movedSol);
  console.log('tokenBalanceBefore', tokenBalanceBefore);
  console.log('tokenBalanceAfter', tokenBalanceAfter);
  console.log('tokenBalanceChanged', tokenBalanceChanged);
}
```